# Jquery Plugin to upload photo and display it a image control for asp.net application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, plugins

Recently, I was asked to develop a form where a person can upload his photo and display it with certain re-sizing of the image that is uploaded.

Can anybody help me to get a Jquery plugin to upload the photo with re-sizing features and display it an image control for asp.net application?

Any code example for the above will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

[Upload and Crop Images with jQuery, JCrop and ASP.NET](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/95/Upload-and-Crop-Images-with-jQuery-JCrop-and-ASP.NET)

Please note that the whole solution is not wrapped into a website.
You have to spend time with it and understand it.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Hi,                                                                      Thanks a lot for  your reply. But I don't want any cropping functionality for this requirement. My requirement is on upload of the photo ,it should be displayed with some re-sizing constraint in an image control above the file upload control.